# Apache httpd - Updating return code when Location header is present

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

We have a custom web application, which is setting Location header to redirect to a new page, but application is sending a return code of 200 (instead of 302). Browser is ignoring the Location header and does nothing due to return code 200.

Custom web application is front-ended (reverse proxy) by Apache httpd server.

Is there any way to update return code in Apache to 302 or send a redirect , when Location header is present and return code is 200?